# Counting a column if a specific string is in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of ranks and I need to determine the count of each rank (1-5) as long as its tag (column 1) is the same as the tag specified on the output table. This is to be placed into a separate table on another sheet showing the percentage total of each rank. From the pictures bellow, I have input the percentages by hand, but wish to use a formula to do this automatically. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Output table:

[image: output table]

Input column:

[image: input column]

Answer (score 1):

This would be a perfect time to learn about PivotTables. Give your data some headings that describe the columns eg "Team" and "Rank". Then select the data and headings and go to Insert > PivotTable.

Then drag the "Team" to the rows area and "Rank" to the columns area, then "Team" to the values area (I suggest Team as it is not numerical, so the default will to count how many times each team has had each rank which is what you want - if you choose ti use Rank it will default to adding them up which you don't want and would have to switch from Sum to Count).

This just counts how many time each Team has been 1st, 2nd 3rd etc. Right click one of the results and select "Show Values As >" then "% of Row".
You can turn off the grand totals but I leave this an exercise for you to figure out (hint: PivotTables>Design ribbon)
Hope this helps and gets you started with the amazing formula-free magic of PivotTables!

Answer (score 0):

For the rows and columns in your example,
and assuming that your input sheet and your output sheet
are called “Input” and “Output”, respectively,

- In the “Output” sheet, fill in cells `B2:F2` with `1` through `5`,
  and enter `AB1` and `CD2` into `A3` and `A4`. 
  If you need these to be generated automatically from the “Input” sheet,
  please say so.
- in cell `B3` of the “Output” sheet, enter

  ```
  =COUNTIFS(Input!$A:$A, Output!$A3, Input!$B:$B, Output!B$2) / COUNTIFS(Input!$A:$A, Output!$A3)
  ```
- drag/fill to the right to Column F and down to Row 4, and
- format as percent.

Explanation:

- The denominator (the part to the right of the `/`) is

  ```
  COUNTIFS(Input!$A:$A, Output!$A3)
  ```

  This counts the number of rows on the Input sheet where Column A
  contains the “tag” from Column A of the current row of the Output sheet. 
  For `Output!$A3` = `AB1`, this is 6.
- The numerator (the part to the left of the `/`) is

  ```
  COUNTIFS(Input!$A:$A, Output!$A3, Input!$B:$B, Output!B$2)
  ```

  This is a refinement of the above;
  it counts the number of rows on the Input sheet
  where Column A contains the “tag” from Column A of the current row
  of the Output sheet,
  and Column B contains the number from Row 2 of the current column
  of the Output sheet. 
  For `Output!$A3` = `AB1` and `Output!B$2` = `1`, this is 3.
- So the result of the division is 3/6 = 0.5 = 50%.

Comment: Thanks for this, would this work if I selected the entire row as in A:A and so on as the input sheet changes size frequently?

Comment: Yes.    I updated the answer to show that.